# How can I make my Flutter app fast in release mode?

Tags: flutter, flutter-debug

My Flutter app runs fast in debug mode but slow in release mode. what could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` then `flutter run --release`. Try it then.